# Release note notification

Tags: email

We are looking for a solution that can track when we send out the release notes to our clients and then storing the notes externally for the clients.  If there is one solution for both that would be great but we will probably put our release notes on our blog and just point clients there.

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about testing, but about release documentation

Comment: Sounds like you need something like outlook and an rss feed.

Answer (score 0):

We have a mailing list set up with [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) with our customers email to send out release notes. The release information isn't public. You can track emails with Google Analytics. The clients will be able to refer to all previously published emails.